# How to count Specific words on RichTextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program where i need to count how many females and Males are in the file that has been read into the richtextbox, but I'm not sure how to do that , in the file has the name, gender,specific job . I have to count between 15 different people

for example : " Donna,Female,Human Resources.",

This is what I have so far:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr;
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    sr = new StreamReader("MOCK_DATA.txt");
    string data;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        data = sr.ReadLine();
        richTextBox1.AppendText(data + "\n");
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] data = richTextBox1.Text.Split(',');
    for (int n = 0; n < data.Length; n++)
    {
        if (data[n] == richTextBox1.Text)
            n++;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the plain text from a RichTextBox (stolen from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754041(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
string StringFromRichTextBox(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
        rtb.Document.ContentStart, 
        // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
        rtb.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    // The Text property on a TextRange object returns a string
    // representing the plain text content of the TextRange.
    return textRange.Text;
}
```

Basic word counting routine:

```
int CountWord(string textToSearch, string word)
{ 
    int count = 0;
    int i = textToSearch.IndexOf(word);
    while (i != -1)
    {
        count++;
        i = textToSearch.IndexOf(word, i+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Putting it together:

```
var plainText = StringFromRichTextBox(richTextBox1);
var countOfMale = CountWord(plainText, "Male");
var countOfFemale = CountWord(plainText, "Female");
```

Comment: I don't get how i can count an specific word with this code

Comment: @LeonardoKafuri you didn't specify that you are using WinForms (add it in the tags), so you got a WPF answer

Comment: @Slai I'm using winforms

Answer (score 0):

```
private void toolStripButton81_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                    string findterm = string.Empty;
                    findterm = toolStripTextBox2.Text;
                    // the search term - specific word
                    int loopCount = 0;
                    // count the number of instance
                    int findPos = 0;

                    // depending on checkbox settings
                    // whole word search or match case etc

                    try
                    {
                        while (findPos < GetRichTextBox().Text.Length)
                        {
                            if (wholeWordToolStripMenuItem.CheckState == CheckState.Checked & matchCaseToolStripMenuItem.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                            {
                                findPos = GetRichTextBox().Find(findterm, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord | RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                            }
                            else if (wholeWordToolStripMenuItem.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                            {
                                findPos = GetRichTextBox().Find(findterm, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                            }
                            else if (matchCaseToolStripMenuItem.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                            {
                                findPos = GetRichTextBox().Find(findterm, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                findPos = GetRichTextBox().Find(findterm, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                            }
                            GetRichTextBox().Select(findPos, toolStripTextBox2.Text.Length);


                            findPos += toolStripTextBox2.Text.Length + 1;
                            loopCount = loopCount + 1;

                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        findPos = 0;

                    }
                    // at the end bring the cursor at the beginning of the document
                    GetRichTextBox().SelectionStart = 0;
                    GetRichTextBox().SelectionLength = 0;
                    GetRichTextBox().ScrollToCaret();
                    // Show the output in statusbar
                    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Instances: " + loopCount.ToString();               
}
```